# Can't access Members page

Tags: members

I have an ExpressionEngine [site](http://musicfilmweb.tv/), using **v2.7.3**.

I appear to have lost access to the Members page in the back-end - no longer finding it in Control Panel or through Admin menu.

I have a purchased license, arranged by my then-developer in 2013 (would have been in September or October of that year).

But the module seems to have vanished. How do I access or regain access?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Has the module been uninstalled? 
or has your user permissions/group permissions for member related admin been revoked?

If the module still exists and is enabled, you should be able to see it via the CP link yoursite.url/admin.php?/cp/members/view_all_members